# How to coordinate Javascript method call based on form field check?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In the following code, how do I synchronize the calling of do_something()
based on a successful addLoadEvent(check_email) ?  Surrounding it in
an if() {} does not work.  Do I need to use Event/EventListener ?  If so, how?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
</head>

...
<form action="#">

<label for="email">Enter email address <img src="email.gif" alt="" /></label>
    <input class="email_class" id="email" value="" />

...
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

foo.js:

```
function check_email()
{
    in_Forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for (var i = 0; i < in_Forms.length; i++)
    {
        in_Forms[i].onsubmit = function ()
        {
            return check_this_email(this);
        }
    }
}

function check_this_email(some_email) {
    var ret_val = false;
    var in_Inputs;

    in_Inputs = some_email.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < in_Inputs.length; i++) {
        if (in_Inputs[i].className == "email_class")
        {
            if (bad_email_check ...)
            {
                ret_val = true;
                alert('enter valid email');
            }
        }
    }
    return ret_val;
}

function addLoadEvent(some_function)
{
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function')
    {
        window.onload = some_function;
    }
    else
    {
        window.onload = function()
        {
            oldonload();
            some_function();
        }
    }
}

addLoadEvent(check_email);

if (email_address_correctly_entered){
  do_something();
}
```

Comment: Question is unclear. Add more details.

Comment: I'm looking for a mechanism where the do_something() method only gets called *after* the email field validation is successful, which in turn gets triggered by pressing the "SUBMIT" button.  So, this should be the sequence of tasks: form loads, email field gets filled and "SUBMIT" button gets pushed, if email field value is correct call do_something().

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
in_Inputs = some_email.getElementsByTagName("input");

var model = {
   index: 0,
   ret_val: false
}

function check_this_email(in_Inputs, model) {

    if(model.index > in_Inputs.length){
        return model.ret_val;
    }

    bad_email_check(in_Inputs, model, check_this_email);   
}


function bad_email_check(in_Inputs, index, callback){
      //check      email in_Inputs[model.index]
      //if valid email model.ret_val = true
      model.index++
      if(model.ret_val){
           do_something(callback, in_Inputs, model);
      }
      else{
           callback(in_Inputs, model);
      }        
}

function do_something(callback, in_Inputs, model){
    //do something

    callback(in_Inputs, model);
}
```

Working example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d81wmm61/

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in my comments above, the sequence of tasks should be: form loads, email field gets filled and "SUBMIT" button gets pushed, if email field value is correct call do_something().